# Byebug does not update local variable on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, byebug

Here's my code:

```
# please_just_work.rb
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require

byebug
puts "a = #{a}"
```

Inside the byebug session I set the value of `a`, but it remains undefined:

```
[1, 5] in /home/paper/tmp/debug.rb
   1: require 'bundler/setup'
   2: Bundler.require
   3: 
   4: byebug
=> 5: puts "a = #{a}"
(byebug) a = 1
1
(byebug) continue
Traceback (most recent call last):
please_just_work.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `a' for main:Object (NameError)
```

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `@a` instead of `a`. I did not find this in the documentation, so I'll leave the answer here for whoever faces this same issue.

Comment: `@a` is not a local variable but an instance variable (of the `main` object in this case). It has a different scope than a local variable and can not be use interchangeably.

Comment: @HolgerJust why does modifying the local variable in byebug not reflect in the subsequent `puts` statement?

Comment: That's how closures work in Ruby. From within a closure (that is: the execution context of a byebug session but also e.g. a proc or block), you can access and set variables which were already defined. You can however not introduce new variables which were not already added as a local variable in the surrounding scope.